# Need all elements in a row to be the length of the longest sibling

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have some dynamically generated buttons, the button text may be a single word, or a small sentence. So I need the buttons to autosize to their content (i.e. can't use a fixed width).

But I also need all the buttons to be the same size, based on the size of the largest button. I know I can do this in JavaScript quite easily. I've provided an example of that below so you can see the expected result.

But I wondered if there was a way to do it just using CSS?

```js
// Quick and dirty just for example purposes
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.container_two > button'),
      biggest = {w:0, h:0};

  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    var size = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
    biggest.w = biggest.w < size.width ? size.width : biggest.w;
    biggest.h = biggest.h < size.height ? size.height : biggest.h;
  });
  
  //console.log(biggest);

  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.style.width = Math.ceil(biggest.w)+'px';
    // btn.style.height = biggest.h+'px'; -- flexbox will do this for us
  });
});
```

```css
strong { display: block; text-align:center;margin-bottom:1em; font-size: 20px; }
hr { margin: 1.5em 0 1em; }
button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  outline: none;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<strong>Original</strong>
<div class="container container_one">
  <button>?</button>
  <button>Yep sure, why not do it later?</button>
  <button>Somewhere<br />over<br />the<br />rainbow</button>
</div>

<hr />

<strong>Javascript Solution</strong>
<div class="container container_two">
  <button>?</button>
  <button>Yep sure, why not do it later?</button>
  <button>Somewhere<br />over<br />the<br />rainbow</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Set the width of the container to shrink wrap the content (`width: fit-content`)
- Use grid properties to distribute container space equally, which will set all buttons to the width of the longest element. (`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` or `1fr 1fr 1fr`).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>?</button>
  <button>Yep sure, why not do it later?</button>
  <button>Somewhere<br />over<br />the<br />rainbow</button>
</div>
```

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Check `fit-content` in [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content) for full compatibility data.

Comment: I knew it would have something to do with getting the container to autosize in order to evenly distribute the columns, but I just couldn't work it out. Haven't used any of the intrinsic sizing css yet so I guess I have much more CSS to learn!

Thanks for the response. It looks correct on here, hoping I haven't over-simplified my question (and therefore lost some real-world nuances) and it works on my website too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), just add it to the button and all buttons will grow to the same ratio if you make the ratio the same:

```css
strong { 
  display: block; 
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:1em; 
  font-size: 20px; 
}

button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1; /* you can also use flex-grow: 1; */
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  outline: none;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
  max-width: 813px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* change the width of the container in order to not fill the entire screen and keep to the required size */
}
```

```html
<strong>Original</strong>
<div class="container container_one">
  <button>?</button>
  <button>Yep sure, why not do it later?</button>
  <button>Somewhere<br />over<br />the<br />rainbow</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-grow` won't size the buttons to the length of the longest one. It just distributes space equally. Run your code on a full screen.

Comment: right, the outer container can be altered to have the width needed to contain the uniform buttons. your answer works, but if flexbox is required, I would start by using flex-grow.

Comment: Flexbox is not required, according the question (*"But I wondered if there was a way to do it just using CSS?"*). More importantly, your solution still doesn't work when the container size is altered. (Hence why I shifted over to Grid.)

Comment: changing the width and centering wouldn't have the same effect?

Comment: I don't see it in your code. Still distributing all space; no correlation to width of longest sibling; Perhaps post a revised solution.

Comment: just updated, I read the question differently, and you did edit the question to better understand what they meant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. Admittedly I was struggling to find the best way to explain my issue, it's why I did the JS version in the hope it would make up for my poor explanation.